# filedownloading is making the file to view instead of download in drupal7

Tags: 7

Hi i have followed Working with files in Drupal 7 and created the content type for file download.Everything is working fine i can upload a file and displaying it in the front page.But when i click on particular file for downloading it is just viewing the file in another tab in the browser with url like this

drupal7.22/sites/default/files/file.txt

I can view the file but not able to download it.Can you just say me where i did the mistake.

Comment: You have simply file field in content type? If so, then browser's default behaviour is respected, and txt files are, by default, opened in browser. If your manual added anything to this, tell us what else you have done, and how.

Comment: No in content type i just have a file field

Comment: As @Mołot mentions this is simply a browser issue. Most browsers will open files with an extension of .txt internally, unless of course the file sends a force-download header (which won't happen in Drupal as it just passes through requests for existing files without getting involved). Try changing your browser settings to force-download those files, or simply click 'File -> Save As...' as with any other document viewed inside your browser

Answer (score 1):

Read [Force Files to Download Instead of Showing Up in the Browser](https://drupal.org/node/417866) as the page suggests you can achieve this by adding these lines to  `.htaccess` file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|odf|pdf|rtf|txt)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Or alter mime type

Comment: Good answer, I'm not sure this'll work for Internet Explorer though. It can be a bit funny about attachments. Not that we should care about IE these days anyway, but probably worth mentioning